# IntelliSense: a member of type "const char *const []" cannot have an in-class initializer

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio-2013, intellisense, const-char

Consider:

```
class Note
{
public: 
    // ...
private:
    static const char* const NOTE_NAMES[12] =
            { "C", "C#", "D", "D#", "E", "F", "F#", "G", "G#", "A", "A#", "B" };
}
```

<strike>While it compiles fine,</strike> IntelliSense gave me an error:

> IntelliSense: a member of type "const char *const [12]" cannot have an in-class initializer

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You need to add `constexpr` for this code to be valid.

Comment: The C++ standard allows only static constant integral or enumeration types to be initialized inside the class.

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate.

Comment: Nothing to be sorry for :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the C++ Standard

> If a non-volatile const static data member is of **integral or
>   enumeration type**, its declaration in the class definition can specify
>   a brace-or-equal-initializer in which every initializer-clause that is
>   an assignmentexpression is a constant expression

So your code does not satisfy the C++ Standard.

On the other hand

> A static data member of **literal** type can be declared in the class
>   definition with the **constexpr specifier**; if so, its declaration shall
>   specify a brace-or-equal-initializer in which every initializer-clause
>   that is an assignment-expression is a constant expression

So to get the valid code you should write

```
static constexpr char* const NOTE_NAMES[12] =
        { "C", "C#", "D", "D#", "E", "F", "F#", "G", "G#", "A", "A#", "B" };
```